# Firestore Query Not Working according to the security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Cloud Firestore and i am trying to change my security rule.This is the condition I want

Only users whose phone number is in any documents in the Teacher collection can read the only his/her documents inside the Teacher collection

Here is code i have written

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Teachers/{teachers}{
    allow read: if((resource.data.mobno == request.resource.data.mobno) )
  allow update:if((request.resource.data.mobno == resource.data.mobno))


  }        


      }
    }
```

This is the client side query

```
 Teacherref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Teachers");      
Teacherref.whereEqualTo("mobno",mobilecredential).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().isEmpty()){
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot data:queryDocumentSnapshots){
                        teacherdata=data.toObject(TeacherLoginModel.class);
                        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(teacherdata.getStatus()))signinuser(data);
                        else if(teacherdata.getStatus().equals("signout"))signinuser(data);
                        else {Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "You Are Already logged In Different Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            predialog.dismiss();}
                    }
                }
                else{
                    predialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Signin.this,"Please Check Your Credentials ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Signin.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or the app is not working as you want?

Comment: Its showing Permission denied

Comment: Can you try using this path? `DocumentReference Teacherref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("Teachers/"+<current_user_uid>); ` instead of `whereEqualTo`? I am assuming this query is done by the user itself. Then use the if-exists logic?

Comment: It will not work as the person is not login yet actually only those teacher can signup in the app whose no is already there in the database.thats why i am first check whether the number entered by the user exist in the database or not and if its exist he can signup

Comment: If you want your non-authenticated user's to somehow access your app, I'll strongly suggest you to use Firebase cloud functions. When a user enter's a phone number, create a node of that phone number in Firebase realtime database and then further use an `onCreate()` trigger to function your app. This way you won't have to worry about the Firestore rules and also your database paths from your clients.

Comment: But this not solves my problem i want that teacher can only upadate ans read their own profile and not the profile of other.And for this i have to check the mobno as stated in the rules

Comment: Be clear: You are saying only Teachers can use the app to check phone numbers?

Comment: let me clarify each and every thing:- only those teach can signup in the app whose phone no is already is in the database probably added by the admin and after he has successfully signing up .The can only read and update their own data and not the data of other teachers which is inside the Teacher's collection

Comment: Yeah the previous comment that I explained regarding taking a tour via cloud functions answers your first question. When the phone number entered reaches your database, you need to use cloud functions to check if phone number exists. If it does, proceed else return an error.

Comment: I  dont know node js can you please suggest me a way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will read in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource), `request.resource` corresponds to "the new resource value, **present on write requests only**".

So you cannot use `request.resource` in a `read` rule.

Comment: Its not working on write either.I tried its says permission denied

Comment: Your `update` rule shoudl work. Did you try to check it with the simulator in the Firebase console?

Comment: Sorry yes its working on write is there any way to implement it in read also